# Having trouble specifying the width of a colored div to display on hover

Tags: html, css, navigation, position

I'm making a navigation bar. When the mouse is hovering over text on the navbar, the area behind it changes color, but I can't seem to specify the width of this color change (it only displays as the width of the list element that contains the text). Here's my html:

```
<div class="portland"></div>
<div class="title">PDX</div>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="table">
        <span class="color"><li class="item"><a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a></li></span>
        <span class="color"><li class="item"><a class="navlink" href="#">Groups</a></li></span>
        <span class="color"><li class="item"><a class="navlink" href="#">Events</a></li></span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 160%;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }

.color:hover {
  display: inline;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px; }

.table {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto; }

.item {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: none; }

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: green; }
```

Whenever I hover, the orange extends out 30px (the length of .item, the 'li' elements). I've tried negative padding values to no avail, and I can make the orange display (.color) go past .item with higher padding values, but I can't reduce it below 30px. I'm trying to show the color with a width less than the .items without it effecting the positioning of the .items in my navbar. What's going on?

Summary: How do I specify the dimensions of a div to display a color on hover?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: Thanks everyone for the answers. The problem was the spans have to be in the list elements. Here's my fixed code:

```
<ul class="table">
    <li class="item"><span class="color"><a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a></span></li>
    <li class="item"><span class="color"><a class="navlink" href="#">Groups</a></span></li>
    <li class="item"><span class="color"><a class="navlink" href="#">Events</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

And the relevent CSS:

```
  .color:hover {
  display: inline;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px; }
```

Turns out I wasn't as SPAN-TASTIC as I thought! Haha! Right, guys? ... guys...?

Comment: First of all: `<li class="item"><span class="color">` instead of  `<span class="color"><li class="item">`. `ul` should contain only `li`s.

Comment: why use the <span> ? the way I see it, you can remove the span and do something like: .item:hover{ background-color: #whatever; }

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/8MJbY/

Comment: Thanks guys, I put the spans within the li's and its all working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EjIQuBAK/1/edit)***

`UL` means ***Unordered List***, not *unordered spans*

`UL` is not supposed to take care about `SPAN` elements but `LI`
therefore:

```
<ul class="table">
   <li class="item"><span class="color"><a class="navlink" href="#">Home</a></span>
   <!-- more LI here -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 160%;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; }
.color{
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  background:green;
}
.color:hover {
  background-color: orange;
}

.table {
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto; }

.item {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```